# Returning temporary object and binding to const reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants, temporary-objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a const reference prolong the life of a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary)

My compiler doesn't complain about assigning temporary to const reference:

```
string foo() {
  return string("123");
};

int main() {
  const string& val = foo();
  printf("%s\n", val.c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

Why? I thought that string returned from `foo` is temporary and val can point to object which lifetime has finished. Does C++ standard allow this and prolongs the lifetime of returned object?

Comment: Yes, the temporary's lifetime is prolonged as long as it's a **const** reference.

Comment: That's not exactly a duplicate of 2784262, which (should) treat the case where the reference is a class member. The behavior is different.

Comment: @aberaud not only this is not a duplicate, it is a much better question I am glad I found.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This is a C++ feature. The code is valid and does exactly what it appears to do.

Normally, a temporary object lasts only until the end of the full expression in which it appears. However, C++ deliberately specifies that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself, and thus avoids what would otherwise be a common dangling-reference error. In the example above, the temporary returned by `foo()` lives until the closing curly brace.

**P.S:** This only applies to stack-based references. It doesn’t work for references that are members of objects.

Full text: [GotW #88: A Candidate For the “Most Important const” by Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).

Comment: Also, please notice that through no copy is done on the string here, a copy constructor for string must exists and be accessible.

Comment: re the **P.S**, this is very important, and the dupe SO thread linked above has good illustrations of this

Comment: @xryl669 Does [c++17 Guaranteed copy elision](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html) mean copy constructor is no longer necessary? quote: ``` when the source object is a temporary ```

Comment: @dashesy What do you mean? A copy constructor was _never_ "necessary" in such cases. In practice, if the `return` expression of `f()` returned an unnamed _rvalue_, RVO would almost certainly have kicked in and elided the copy construction, instead directly constructing the returned object in the caller's receiving location (variable). Had the `return` expression returned a named object, NRVO might've done the same. What C++17's guaranteed copy elision achieves is to _require_ elision in the former, simpler case of RVO.

Comment: @underscore_d yes, no copy is made but xryl669 comment states that still a copy constructor was needed.

Comment: @dashesy Oops, I get it now. Fair question. And thankfully the answer is trivial to find: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38043447/2757035 That's a _yes_. It follows logically from the _guaranteed_ part of the name. If copy elision is guaranteed, then there doesn't need to be an accessible copy or move constructor, for it is guaranteed _not_ to ever be needed.