# C++: Return by reference to return by value

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I've been reading Myers book and came across the item on returning by reference/pointer vs by value.
The point is, if our function for example is like this:

```
ClassA& AddSomething(ClassA classA)
{
  ClassA tempClassA;
  //... do something on tempClassA
  return tempClassA;
}
```

This would not work because we are returning a reference to a object that was created on the stack and it is dead now that the function is done.

He gives two solutions:

1. Using a local static ClassA inside the function. This has its
   problems but atleast we can be sure that object exists.
2. Return as an object:

   ```
   ClassA AddSomething(ClassA classA)
   {
     ClassA tempClassA;
     //... do something on tempClassA
     return tempClassA;
   }
   ```

Now if I'm to do:

```
ClassA obj1;
ClassA obj2 = AddSomething(obj1);
```

My confusion now is, when executing this line:

1. A 'copy' of tempClassA is made and passed to the copy constructor
   of ClassA (to initialize obj2)? OR
2. tempClassA is passed itself to the copy constructor of ClassA,
   because copy constructor takes a reference.

So basically, whats passed to the copy constructor is a reference to tempClassA (which was created in stack inside the function) or a reference to a copy of tempClassA.

Also, another question I have is, I have read that if I get a reference of a function local variable, in that case the local variable will not be deleted.
For example,

```
ClassA & classRef = AddSomething(obj1);
```

In this case, if AddSomething() is returning a reference, then classRef not be pointing to a deleted reference because the local variable will be retained. Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Have a look at [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an object is returned by value, there are two copies taking place: one from the local variable into the return value, and one from the return value into the target object.  However, the implementation is allowed to *elide* one or both of these copies; this is called [return value optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (RVO) in the first case, and [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) in the second.

```
Object some_function() {
    return Object();    // copy Object() into return value; candidate for RVO
}
Object another_function() {
    Object obj;
    return obj;         // copy obj into return value; candidate for NRVO
}
Object result = some_function();   // copy return value into result; candidate for copy elision
```

The second function above is a candidate for a refinement type of RVO called *named* return value optimisation; the simplest form of RVO applies only to return statements that construct the return value inplace.

Regarding your second question, lifetime extension only applies to *const* references to objects returned by value; your code in the second question will not extend the lifetime of any object.  See [Returning temporary object and binding to const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560339/returning-temporary-object-and-binding-to-const-reference) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

At worst, you're right: a copy of `tempClassA` is passed to the copy constructor. But compilers are allowed to eliminate that copy and construct the result in place form `tempClassA`. This is known as the "Return Value Optimization", or RVO. I don't know of a compiler that doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can never return a function local variable by reference. It would NOT work even if you used const reference to capture the returned value like this:

```
const ClassA& classRef = AddSomething(obj1);
```

Because if AddSomething returns a local object by reference, it'll be a dangling reference to a non-existing object by the time classRef gets to reference it.