# C++ Returned Copy Object

Tags: c++

I have a class with a function that returns a copy of a private member:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyString str;

public:

    MyString getStr() { return str; }
}
```

Another function, func, takes in a `const &MyString` that is bound to a statement handle.  When I invoke `func(o.getStr())`, the copy object returned by `getStr` goes out of scope after the `func` call and is no longer valid for the statement handle.  I can create a local variable `MyString ms = o.getStr()` and then pass that to `func`, but I don't want to have to do that multiple times for different getters.  Also, `func` needs to take in a ref since sometimes I need to pass in a local variable and change the value of it after subsequent uses of the statement handle.  Is there a good solution to this?

Comment: store it in a local variable of type MyString initaly and use it as arg for fn func. So you can use the it later from this variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560339/returning-temporary-object-and-binding-to-const-reference

Comment: The lifetime of the return value of `o.getStr()` is until the end of the **statement** that it occurs on. In particular, it still exists for the entirety of the call to `func`.    I'm not sure what you are saying about "func use the ref afterwards", `func` cannot do anything once it has returned. Maybe showing your code for `func` would help.

Comment: It turned out that I needed getStr() to return a const ref.

Answer (score 1):

The `MyString` copy that `getStr()` returns will not go out of scope until `func()` exits, ensuring that `func()` can access the copy.