# Is there a way to be sure that a const reference stored in class will always refer to a valid object?

Tags: c++, reference, temporary, object-lifetime, anonymous-objects

I have written the following sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
  int Value;

  public:
  B(int V) : Value(V) {}

  int GetValue(void) const { return Value;}
};

class A
{
  const B& b;

  public:
  A(const B &ObjectB) : b(ObjectB) {}

  int GetValue(void) { return b.GetValue();}

};


B b(5);

A a1(B(5));

A a2(b);

A a3(B(3));


int main(void)
{
  std::cout << a1.GetValue() << std::endl;
  std::cout << a2.GetValue() << std::endl;
  std::cout << a3.GetValue() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with mingw-g++ and executed on Windows 7, I get

```
6829289
5
1875385008
```

So, what I get from the output is that the two anonymous object are destroyed as the initialization has completed, even if they are declared in a global context.

From this my question: does is exist a way to be sure that a const reference stored in class will always refer to a valid object?

Comment: A popular way to mitigate this is using smart pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Remember that references are pointers under the hood, and normally don't control the lifetime of the object they reference (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560339/returning-temporary-object-and-binding-to-const-reference) for an exception, although it doesn't apply in this case). I would recommend just having a B object, if this is in a piece of code that you need.

Also, you could utilize an object such as a `shared_ptr` in C++11, which will only eliminate the object once both the pointer in the function and in the object have been destroyed.

Comment: References don't have to be pointers under the hood; and in any case that doesn't matter, as references and pointers have different semantics.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do in `class A`:

```
A(B&&) = delete;
```

That way, the two lines that try to construct an `A` from a `B` temporary will fail to compile.

That obviously won't prevent you providing some other `B` object with a lifetime shorter than the `A` object referencing it, but it's a step in the right direction and may catch some accidental/careless abuses.  (Other answers already discuss design scenarios and alternatives - I won't cover that same ground / whether references can be safe(r) in the *illustrated* scenario is already an important question.)