# Which way is preferred to store returned objects for use in a function?

Tags: c++, c++03, return-value-optimization

I use functions that return an object, like `Bar()` in the following example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
private:
    int x, y;
}

Foo Bar()
{
    return Foo(1, 2);
}
```

Not involving those with need for extra tools or lines of code (like returning a pointer or using `std::auto_ptr`), I know two ways to store the returned object in a local variable when I want to read it (call `const` methods only):

```
const Foo  foo1 = Bar();
const Foo &foo2 = Bar();
```

Both of them are correct in C++, the first option should have [no copy overhead](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/return-by-value-optimization.html).

Are there any differences between these two options in terms of performance? Should one of them be preferred?

---

**EDIT**

OK, I’ll add a reason why I care about this. Assume the implementation of *Bar* gets changed:

```
Foo globalFoo(1, 2);  // This object could also be a class member.
Foo &Bar()
{
    return globalFoo;
}
```

My original piece of code defining `foo1` and `foo2` should still work but `foo2` gets bound to `globalFoo`, so it requires less memory<sup>1</sup>, right? Is therefore using references better since it could profit from such changes of interface?

<sup>1</sup> Assuming the usual case that an object takes more memory than a pointer.

Comment: later on in your code, accessing `foo2` will be more expensive than `foo1`

Comment: If you only use the variable(s) inside the calling function, and don't store them for later processing (though you can't really do it with references), then the two uses are pretty much equivalent. They are not the same though, as in one case you have a copy and in the other a constant reference. Also, having a reference is an extra step of indirection, but the compiler will probably optimize it away. But if you're really worried, you should of course measure it, and try to profile it, and possibly look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: I would not use a reference to temporary object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560339/returning-temporary-object-and-binding-to-const-reference

Comment: @PiotrS.: Probably not; both options should produce identical code, assuming an optimising compiler. The compiler knows which object the reference is bound to, so there's no need to dereference it at runtime.

Comment: `foo2` is a reference, not a pointer. References might not require any storage.