# return const reference of subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, const-reference

## What I know

I know that returning a const reference of a temporary object is ok! (like this example:)

```
class A {
public:
  virtual const A& clone () { return (A()); }
  virtual std::string name() const { return ("A"); }
};
```

[Returning temporary object and binding to const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560339/returning-temporary-object-and-binding-to-const-reference)

## But!

If I would want to do that, It is still correct:

```
class B : public A {
public:
  virtual const A& clone () { return (B()); }
  virtual std::string name() const { return ("B"); }
};
```

I would think yes, but in execution time, the returned object is still considered as a A object (like in this example:)

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
  B bb;
  A* aa = &bb;

  std::cout << aa->clone().name() << std::endl;
}
```

output

```
valgrind ./a.out
==14106== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14106==    at 0x401BF9: main (main.cpp:8)
==14106==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14106==    at 0x401BF2: main (main.cpp:8)
B
```

It's a B.. yay.. but this warning is quite horrifing....

## Edit

Thanks to you i know see my error... but i would want to know some other things about it...

When this is executed, what exactly in the stack is happening?

Comment: @Chris Drew... errrh I doesn't understand

Comment: "I know that returning a const reference of a temporary object is ok!" No it isn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560339/returning-temporary-object-and-binding-to-const-reference "This is a C++ feature. The code is valid and does exactly what it appears to do.", "C++ deliberately specifies that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself"

Comment: I think a better question would be why do you even want to do this? All `clone()` implementations I have seen return either a `Base*` or a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` because you are transferring ownership of a new heap allocated object.

Comment: @CollioTV Nevermind, I didn't read your second example properly.

Comment: @CollioTV "C++ deliberately specifies that binding a temporary object to a reference to const **on the stack** lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself" don't you see the problem?

Comment: Maybe you want to use a `copy constructor` instead of `clone` pattern.

Comment: @CollioTV: "I know that returning a const reference of a temporary object is ok!" You know wrong. Returning a reference to a temporary object is never OK. The SO question you linked is not even remotely similar to what you are doing in your code.

Comment: @Slava now i see the problem... i'm sooo dumb><

Comment: @AndreyT know i see why, please excuse me....

Comment: "What is happening": since the name() method is virtual, calling it requires reading a 'vtable' pointer from the object, which points to a table of methods. But the pointer (initialized by the constructor B()) could have been modified, since by now the B() has been destroyed, and the memory possibly re-used for something else. valgrind detected the possibility of that. In general, ~B() will change that pointer back to point at A's vtable before ~A() runs; but in this example the compiler probably left that out (since ~A doesn't do anything ) so you got B::name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Binding a reference to a temporary extends the lifetime of the temporary...except when it doesn't. §12.2 [class.temporary]/p5, emphasis added:

> The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is
>   the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound
>   persists for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s *ctor-initializer* (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the *full-expression*
>     containing the call.
> - **The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not extended; the temporary is
>     destroyed at the end of the *full-expression* in the return statement.**
> - A temporary bound to a reference in a *new-initializer* (5.3.4) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the
>     *new-initializer*.

The case in the question you linked (`std::string foo(); const std::string & s = foo();`) is OK; the lifetime of the temporary returned by `foo()` is extended until `s`'s lifetime ends. In your code, the temporary is bound to the returned value, and per the third bullet point above, its lifetime is not extended, and your function returns a dangling reference.

Usually speaking, `clone()` functions should return a pointer to a heap-allocated copy.

Comment: @T.C. So, what if I have a method that returns a const reference to a subclass (or member var) of *this? The caller must be aware that the reference doesn't outlive the object on which the method was called; and if that object is a temporary, the language won't extend its lifetime by these rules, since the reference isn't being taken in the calling code, but in the method. Correct?