# Understanding const reference in assignment when constructing object

Tags: c++, c++14, variable-assignment, const-reference

Today I see this piece of code and I'm wondering to know what it is exactly doing this const reference in an assignment where a new object is created. (I don't know how to name this kind of assignments.)

```cpp
std::string const& p = s.c_str(); // s is a std::string
```

I understand that something like `std::string const& p = s;` will create a reference `p` to `s`, but in the line shown we are creating a new object (using the raw pointer from `std::string::c_str`).

I've made a MCVE in [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4353c4b23f0a670) with this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(std::string const& s)
{
    std::string const& p = s.c_str(); // << here
    
    std::cout << s << " " << p << " " << &s << " " << &p << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo("hello");
}
```

And, as expected the output is showing that a new object was created:

```
hello hello 0x7ffdd54ef9a0 0x7ffdd54ef950
```

So, my question is: *Is this actually doing something I'm not able to see? Does it have any problem (like a dangling reference) in the code?*

Comment: I once stumbled into a Q/A where the life-time of a temporary in a const reference was discussed. To me, it was surprising to learn that the life-time is in fact until end of scope where the const reference is defined in.  [Does a const reference class member prolong the life of a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784304/7478597), [Returning temporary object and binding to const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11560472/7478597), [GotW #88: A Candidate For the “Most Important const”](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This clarifies a lot too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [**`std::string::c_str's documentation`**](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/), it **returns**:

> a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object. That is, a `const char*`.

So when you wrote:

```
std::string const& p = s.c_str();
```

In the above statement, the `const char*` that was returned on the **right hand side** is used to create a **temporary** object of type `std::string` using a [**converting constructor**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes `const char*` as argument.

Next, the lvalue reference `p` on the **left hand side** is bound to that temporary obect. And in doing so, the **lifetime** of the temporary is **extended**.

To answer your last question, there is no dangling reference in your program.

Comment: Yes, this is what I understood too, but have no idea what happened with the reference to the temporary object, if it produced a memory leak, or so.

Comment: @cbuchart There is no memory leak. The lifetime of the temporary is extended as mentioned at the end of my answer.

Comment: Without life-time extension, the problem would be dangling reference, but still no memory leaks.

Comment: @Jarod42 Correct.

Comment: You're right, I've updated the question with this lapse

Answer (score 3):

In fact this construction

```
std::string const& p = s.c_str();
```

does not differ essentially from

```
std::string const p( s.c_str() );
```

but is more confusing.

As for the output of this statement

```
std::cout << s << " " << p << " " << &s << " " << &p << std::endl;
```

then there are outputted two different addresses. The first one is the address of the parameter `s` and the second one is the address of the temporary object of the type `std::string` created in this declaration

```
std::string const& p = s.c_str();
```

by means of the conversion constructor

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

Comment: *"more confusing"* is opinion biased ;-) On the other side, it has the advantage to be sure that no **extra** copies happens (for example, in case the method returns already a const reference, instead of a temporary, especially when used with `auto`).

Comment: Or better `std::string const&& ptemp( s.c_str() ); std::string const& p = ptemp;`?