# ostringstream, .str(), and reseting/clearing the stream

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, temporary-objects

I'm licking my wounds from [Memory Error with std:ostringstream and -std=c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283133/memory-error-with-stdostringstream-and-std-c11), and I have a related question.

If the following returns a temporary so that `reserve` has no effect and the `char*` is not valid:

```
ostringstream oss;
oss.str().reserve(96);

// populate oss

const char* ptr = oss.str().c_str();
// do something with ptr
```

Then how does the following clear the `ostringstream` (from [How to reuse an ostringstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream)):

```
oss.clear(); oss.str("");
```

I understand `clear()` will reset the stream's flags; but as I *now* understand `str("")` will operate on a temporary and not the underlying string.

So how does `str("")` reset the stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are different functions.

`oss.str()` (without parameters) returns a copy to the stream's underlying string, but `oss.str("")` *sets* its underlying string to the value you passed (here an empty string: `""`).

So calling both `clear()` and `str("")` on a `std::stringstream` actually kind of "resets" it.

Notice the two signatures on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str)

Comment: `clear()` resets the error flags.  `str("")` replaces the input data with the given string.  The two are totally unrelated.

Comment: And to be exact: `oss.str()` returns a _copy_ of the stream's underlying string.  In this case, the fact that it's a copy is important.

Comment: Thanks JBL. I can't tell you how many times I vistied a different CCP Reference page. I think its kind of crummy the C++ committee overloaded the the behavior and semantics of `.str()` (in one case a temporary, in another case a pseudo-reference). That's precisely why I thought `.str()` returned a reference to the underlying string.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yep, it's a copy. I wrote "returns ... as a temporary" but it felt awkward, so I removed it, but forgot to mention it's a copy. I'll upvote your comment to stress that.

Comment: @noloader I think you misunderstand the behaviour of the function. There's no "pseudo-reference" as you call it. You are simply passing a string to `str` which then does the assignment to the internal object. At no point does the function give you the internal object.

Comment: @JamesKanze and yes, the two functions are unrelated, but both are used to create the impression of some kind of `reset()` function that leaves the stream in a empty and "clean" (for the lack of a better word) state.

Comment: @noloader In one case it returns nothing (when you _set_ the underlying string content), and in the other case, it returns by value ,which means you have a copy, nothing more.

Comment: Which is, I suppose, what you meant by "kind of".  Neither, of course, actually resets the stream; they only reset a (relatively small) part of it.  The only practical way to get a stream in a "like new" state is to create a new instance.

Comment: "In one case it returns nothing ..  and in the other case, it returns by value..." - that's precisely the point I am trying to make. `str` has different behaviors and meanings depending on how its used. Pick a meaning and use it consistently. If you want two behaviors, then use two different functions names to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes. But it's the closest (I believe, correct me if I'm wrong) we get to some kind of reset.

Comment: @JosephMansfield - "I think you misunderstand the behaviour of the function..." - yes, clearly ;) And it was happening for a long time....

Comment: @noloader Ah but whether or not this is confusing or not is a whole different debate! :P Then, when you say "`str` has different behaviors and meanings depending on how it's used", I'd say "there's two `str` functions, which one?". I got used to it so I don't really see an issue there, but I can understand the confusion it could create.

Comment: @noloader In this case, the committee simply adopted an ubiquitious C++ idiom: overloading functions with an attribute name, with a const version without parameters as the getter, and a non-const version with a new value as the setter.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `str` with no argument returns a copy of the internal string object. That's why it's a temporary object. Calling `str` with a string argument sets the value of the internal string object. It doesn't work on a temporary object.

It seems like you're thinking of it like this:

```
oss.str() = "";
```

But that's not what it is. You're passing `""` to the `str` function so that it can assign it to the internal string.

It's no different to any other getter/setter combination. If you have `getX()`, it typically gets you a copy of some member of the class you're calling it on. If you have `setX(x)`, it typically sets the value of that member. In this case, they're just both called `str`, but one takes an argument and the other doesn't.

Comment: "... it typically gets you a copy of some member of the class you're calling it on" - I actually learned it differently in college (20 years ago or so). If an copy was expensive, you return a reference, not a copy. A string is an expensive object because it requires a call to `new` and a call to `memcpy`. So you would provide a `const` and `non-const` version for `str()` (in my hypothetical and mis-informed case).

Answer (score 2):

From [this `std::ostringstream::str` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str):

> **Parameters**
>
> **`new_str`**     -   new contents of the underlying string

It can be used to get the string, or to *set* the string to the string provided by the functions argument.